# how to read init.d script start argument

Tags: scripts, init.d

In reference to the [following documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto), ***how can i read the start and stop argument***? I want to tell if the computer is booting up or shutting down so that i can run the correct script.

> To make the script run with the start
>   argument at the end of the start
>   sequence, and run with the stop
>   argument at the beginning of the
>   shutdown sequence:
>
> ```
> sudo update-rc.d myscript defaults 98 02
> ```

i want to do something like this:

```
if [ startargument "start" ]          
then
    ./startscript
else
    ./shutdownscript
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
case "$1" in
  start)
        echo "Starting"
        ;;
  stop)
        echo "Stopping $DESC"
        ;;

  restart|force-reload)
        echo "Restarting $DESC"
        ;;
  *)
        N=/etc/init.d/$NAME
        echo "Usage: $N {start|stop|restart|force-reload}" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

- "$1" adresses the 1st parameter fed to the script.
  So you would do `your_script start` or `your_script stop` etc.
- Change the `echo` into the actual action that needs to be executed (or put it underneath it).

The document you are referencing to is old. Very old.

These links will help you with Upstart:

[Upstart getting started](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html)

[Upstart stanzas](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/Stanzas)

[Example #1 'django' server](http://geeknme.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/getting-started-with-upstart-in-ubuntu/)

[Example #2](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/125977)

Comment: (+1) thanks, Does the system automatically send the "start" parameter when it starts the computer?

Comment: No! you need to feed it a 'start' yourself or optionally you could alter the script: you could add in an option that checks for some condition (like set a boolean 'booting=true') and test that and make that do the start for you.

Comment: (+1) The script needs to know automatically from the system... see the quote i placed? It is supposed to be passed in by the system by using (defaults 98 02) but it does not seem to start up on boot.

Comment: Forget the document you linked: it's old and outdated. This one is better http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html (but also a bit more difficult to follow). Upstart is used in Ubuntu and files can include things like `start on startup` and `start on stopped rcS` to make them run when starting and stopping.